# Is this edit scenario a bug?

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30370257/change-the-uitableviews-height-for-headerinsection) and started editing the code to format it properly.

As I finished editing, a user with insufficient privileges to outright edit had [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8148285). This showed up as a little `(1)` next to the edit button, and when I clicked it, the community user had already rejected it.

[image]

However, the edit was subsequently [approved](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30370257/3) by the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8148288)

[image]

Is this scenario a bug? Should this suggested edit have remained in a state where it could be approved?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not a bug, but actually 2 different edits by the same user:

The [first](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8148285) was rejected automatically because someone with full edit privileges edited the post (namely you) while the suggested edit was still pending.  This is by design to prevent suggested edit collision between 2 different users.  The system is designed to prefer edits from users will full edit privileges so any pending suggested edits are automatically rejected when you submitted your edit.

The [second](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8148288) was approved by the OP of the question.

What likely happened is the editor suggested an edit while you were performing your edit.  When they saw there edit was rejected (or just wasn't applied), they proceeded to make the same exact edit.