# Should rejected edits from overlaps be counted as rejected?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I came across this question earlier:

[Is this edit scenario a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294915/is-this-edit-scenario-a-bug?cb=1)

Many users with <2000 reputation consistently make edits to posts to improve upon. As a user with more than 2000 reputation points edit a post, which already has an edit pending, the Community user rejects the suggestion, and the new edit is implemented immediately. I've started to wonder if there was a relationship between this and other things, such as edit bans.

Since these edits aren't actually "rejected", just a sad edit that didn't get enough time for approval (or rejection), should we allow these edits to be added to the "rejected edit" count? As a suggestion took place, perhaps we should have another count, similar to "disputed" flags?